# How to show alert when flutter app is paused?

Tags: flutter, dialog, state, resume, pause

How to show alert on screen when app is in background in flutter
or how to change state of flutter app from pause to resume

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html    you can get  state of app in didChangeAppLifecycleState method

Answer (score 2):

hi the answer is to use WidgetsBindingObserver.
in your app just add

```
class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> with WidgetsBindingObserver{}
```

add the following inside our initState:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
```

didChangeAppLifecycleState will be:

```
@override
     void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
     super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
      if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
       // went to Background
         }
       if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
       // came back to Foreground
       }
    }
```

here is the link of the full article [link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-lifecycle-for-android-and-ios-developers-8f532307e0c7)

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I know this but how when  application is paused in background 
how to make it ,become visible again or in resume

Comment: I don't know what do you mean but when the user came back to the app, please explain  the exact thing you wanna do